# UpdateListItems throws "Cannot access a closed Stream."

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-server, web-services

I have been trying to find out the issue faced for some documents while uploading in libraries using list.asmx service in web application.
The steps i follow:

1. Uploads document using copy service.
2. Update uploaded document properties.

I am facing issue for some documents while updating their properties. I don't know whether it is document size or document type which is causing problem.
If i say it is document size or type, it might be wrong as i have uploaded similar document with same type and larger size with no exception.
Following the code i am using to update document's properties.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement batch = doc.CreateElement("Batch");
        batch.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
        batch.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "1");
        batch.SetAttribute("ViewName", viewname);
        batch.InnerXml = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>" +
                         "<Field Name='ID'>" + id + "</Field>" +
                         "<Field Name='" + columnName + "'>" + colValue + "</Field></Method>";
        XElement xElement = Utility.ToXElement(batch);

        //ListsSoapClient object
        var proxy = Utility.GetServerListProxy();
        proxy.UpdateListItems(listname, xElement);
```

Exception is

> [image: SoapServerException]

Fault exception details:

> Cannot access a closed Stream.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know which line throws the exception?

Comment: UpdateListItems() is the method which throws exception.

Comment: This error occurs when you have two `using` statements for a `Stream` class inside each other and the outer `using` statement is still trying to use the variable from the second `using` statement.

Comment: There is neither **using** is used nor **Stream** class. Works fine for many documents but failing for few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for commenting.

Later i figure out that, the document i was trying to upload had some weird characters other than special characters in file properties attributes.

So after removing those characters, it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also received this error when using SPServices on a root site. The only solution was to create a sub site and use that instead. This is a known bug in certain versions of SPServices.